# String contains an invalid character - Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, blob, paste

I'm having a strange problem. It has to do with an image converting it to canvas. So I can copy images in the internet and on paste I want to get the data from the clipboard and show it to the user but when I try to paste it on firefox I get "String contains an invalid character" and after that when I retry to paste again works just fine. For chrome I'm currently using navigator.clipboard.read but I also tried it with the paste event and it works just fine, it pastes the data on the first time.
I'm using VueJS, here's the code I have:

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
        if (!this.supportsReadNavigator) {
            this.handlePasteEvent(e)
        }
    })
},
created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        // this.handleESC(e)
        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key == 'v') {
            this.handlePasteFromClipboard(e)
        }
    });
},
methods: {
    async handlePasteFromClipboard() {
        if (navigator?.clipboard?.read) {
            this.supportsReadNavigator = true
            const data = await navigator.clipboard.read()
            const clipboardContent = data[0]
            const type = clipboardContent.types[0]
            if (type == 'image/png') {
                this?.$refs['clipboard-modal']?.showModal()
                const blob = await clipboardContent.getType('image/png')
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                this.getDataBlob(url)
            }
        }
    },
    async handlePasteEvent(e) {
        if (e?.clipboardData?.items) {
            const data = e.clipboardData.items;
            const clipboardContent = data[0]
            const type = clipboardContent?.type

            if (clipboardContent.kind === "file" && type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                this?.$refs['clipboard-modal']?.showModal()
                const blob = clipboardContent.getAsFile();
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                this.getDataBlob(url)
            } else if (clipboardContent.kind === "string" && clipboardContent.type === "text/html") {
                const htmlData = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
                
                if (!htmlData.includes('<img')) return

                const div = document.createElement('div')
                document.body.appendChild(div)
                div.innerHTML = htmlData

                const img = div.firstElementChild
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
                
                canvas.width = img?.width;
                canvas.height = img?.height;
                
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                document.body.appendChild(canvas)
                
                try {
                    const imageDataURL = await  canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    let blob = this.dataURLToBlob(imageDataURL)

                    this?.$refs['clipboard-modal']?.showModal()

                    this.clipboard_img = imageDataURL
                    this.clipboard_img_blob = await this.blobToFile(blob);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e?.message);
                    this.$refs.show.showFlashError(e?.message || 'Something went wrong')
                    this.$nextTick(() => this?.$refs['clipboard-modal']?.hideModal())
                }

                div.style.display = 'none'
                canvas.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I'll give more info if you need. Thank you

Comment: Where does the error fire from? The console's message should have a trace you can follow.

Comment: The problem could have something to do with the fact that a compressed image file (jpeg, png, etc) will (or certainly can) have byte sequences that cannot be recognized as Unicode codepoints. So if the browser thinks it's supposed to treat your dropped image file as string (UTF-8) content, an image can cause that to break.

Comment: Hey @Kaiido I apologize for not replying earlier, havent been working the past 2 days. You're right the error seems to come from dataURLToBlob method inside try {} as far as I could debug. Here I added the code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wozniak-79z2ks?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue . I modified it a little bit so now we only use paste event, so if u want u can compare firefox with chrome now. Tell me if u need anything else

Comment: Hey @Pointy Also apologize to you for not replying for 2 days, I'm a little behind on this path so I kinda don't understand. Instead here I added the code in sandbox if you want to check it: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wozniak-79z2ks?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue Tell me if u need anything else

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on Firefox 118 on macOS. I had to modify a bit the code for Chrome so that it does`img = div.querySelector("img")` though.

Comment: @Kaiido interesting it didnt work for me but my friend seems to have fixed it, here's the code that works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wozniak-79z2ks?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue I think it has to do with the img.onload. However thank you for taking your time to take a look at my problem